# Is file_put_contents() on Windows not guaranteed to have actually written a file if returning non-FALSE?

Tags: php, windows, io, file-put-contents, php-8

https://www.php.net/file_put_contents

> This function returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or false on failure.

I do this in my wrapper function:

```
$result = file_put_contents(...);

if ($result === false)
    return false;

return true;
```

Should this not mean that as long as my function returns `true`, the file is guaranteed to have been written to the file system?

Normally, it works, but "sometimes" (I cannot reliably reproduce it) it seems as if it has not written the file, at least not in time for the next instruction which reads the written file's contents (for the purpose of safe display). This has frustrated me for a long time now.

Is PHP's `file_put_contents()` not reliable? Is this known? Does it only happen on Windows? Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: When you say "the next instruction" needs to read the file, do you mean another part of the same PHP script, or a separate program? Various kinds of buffering and race conditions could mean that some scenarios which appear to you to be "just after" writing the file appear to the OS as "just before", but it's hard to tell what's relevant without a bit more detail of what you're seeing.

Comment: @IMSoP I mean in the same script, right afterwards. `if (wrapper_function(...)) { /* file not found */ }`

Comment: I think it can also return a boolean that evaluates to false instead of ===. So maybe try '==' as well